# How to use if else inside for loop to increase or add a no. by n

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I've been trying to use if else inside for loop to increase or add a no. by 1 at a specific condition but getting no success

code

```
for i in range(50):
    if (i % 10 == 0):
        num = num + 1 # do something here
        print(num)
```

desired output

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

what i want to achieve is getting the num added by 1 evertime the condition gets true i.e. at 1st value of num should be 0 + 1 = 1 then 1 + 1 = 2 . similarly 3 , 4 , 5 ...

I looked for other answers but none of them worked and sorry for wrong question display please help

Comment: The code you posted works. That is, if you define `num` before the loop, of course.

Comment: You should provide more info on what is going wrong. Right now I don't see any issues with what you are doing, but have no information on how youare defining `num` and what you would want to do in the else clause.

Comment: For clarification: Please show what the output look like before and after i=10.

Comment: what i want to achieve is getting the num added by 1 evertime the condition gets true i.e. at 1st time time value of num should be 0 + 1 = 1 then 1 + 1 =  2 . similarly 3 , 4 , 5 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood what you want, DallogFheir is correct, you just missed defining the 'num' before the loop:

```
num = 0
for i in range(50):
    if (i % 10 == 0):
        num = num + 1 # do something here
        print(num)
```

An alternative is to use the // operator using 'i' itself as the base:

```
for i in range(50):
if (i % 10 == 0):
     # do something here
    print(i//10 + 1)
```